# AWS S3 Not Sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin header when Origin header on request is present

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have an AWS S3 bucket with the following CORS policy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

In my app, I load a page of images from the bucket. The images appear on the page as expected. When I click on one of the images to open it in the Adobe Creative SDK, the SDK fails to load the image because it is blocked by CORS. The SDK takes the url of the image and loads it via AJAX. The SDK has an option to enable CORS and appears to be sending the proper `Origin` header (See screenshot), however AWS is not including the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Header`, causing the image to be blocked by CORS.

I've scoured every question on here about this subject and it seems like no one has a straight answer. There are dozens of questions on this subject that are unanswered, however in many of those cases it appears that the AJAX request isn't sending the Origin header or that the bucket isn't properly configured. In this case, neither of those are true, which is why **this is not a duplicate**.

As you can see in the screenshot, the request includes the `Origin` header, but the response does not include the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. What I would like to know is:
 1. Why isn't S3 sending the proper header if my bucket is properly configured?
 2. Is it possible that when the Adobe Creative SDK requests the image via AJAX, the browser sees that the image is already cached and tried to serve the cached image (which doesn't have the `Origin` header) instead?
 3. If #2 is the case, how can I forcibly add the `Origin` header to the image request? In the app, the image is the background of a div (css `background-image` property).

[image]

Comment: Clearly this is in your cache, and appears to have been cached with the Origin header set in the original request... so, the first question is, did it get there before you configured CORS on the bucket?

Comment: That could be possible in production, but I make a point to clear the cache frequently, so I'd say the image in the cache would have been requested *after* the CORS policy was set. There are two requests per image though, so I'm not sure if that makes a difference. The first request is a standard http get request sent by the browser. The second is an ajax request sent by the SDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a test bucket, enabled CORS, and used your CORS rules.

Note that I am not convinced that `<ExposeHeader>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</ExposeHeader>` is necessary, but it should not do any harm by being present, so I've retained it.

The behavior I observe in testing *is not consistent* with what you are showing in your browser's request/response headers.

Using curl, I set the `Origin:` header to `http://example.com`.  (Yes, that's actually what I set it to... this was not modified in the output below).

```
$ curl -v http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/index.txt -H 'Origin: http://example.com'
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 54.231.98.120...
* Connected to xxxxxxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com (54.231.98.120) port 80 (#0)
> GET /index.txt HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: xxxxxxxxxxxx
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://example.com
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: pF39K26ii42SzxSU2Dt0KT2z7+xmfyiP4yekp9s4DCYJo0jlRwCTDg6QO6f0HMIL4H9b640zq7U=
< x-amz-request-id: 3B18A563CFF4E485
< Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 21:49:21 GMT
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
< Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Last-Modified: Sat, 28 May 2016 21:40:57 GMT
< ETag: "cd21a8c7268dc6af728d180f9a3a81d7"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 71
* Server AmazonS3 is not blacklisted
< Server: AmazonS3
```

Why is this interesting?

S3, with CORS configured and a `<CORSRule>` matching your request, **always** returns the CORS response headers **and** a `Vary:` header (which means "If you vary one of the following headers in your request, I may vary something about my response.")  The headers from the above output that I am referring to, specifically, are these.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
```

There is only one exception I can find to this, which is when there is not a matching CORS rule.  To demonstrate that, I first changed my CORS configuration to `<AllowedOrigin>http://example.com</AllowedOrigin>` and then repeated the request.  Note that the response is almost identical, except that S3 uses the exact origin in the response, and adds `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`.

```
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
```

...however, if I -- still using the more restrictive CORS rule that specifies a specific origin -- then send a request for `Origin: example.org`, which is an origin that is not mentioned in my CORS configuration and has no wildcard `<AllowedOrigin>` to match, S3 responds as though CORS was not configured at all.

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: WJ0QmIZ6jTQYefFi8GjlDQkZKFHDX8/5cmejeulhG1ov3/NdoSXbsTKetYpxvXPML8aUnPNZ/ac=
< x-amz-request-id: 15A03D8B1E08A830
< Date: Sat, 28 May 2016 21:58:34 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache
...etc.
```

This takes me back to my initial conclusion that the request you've shown your browser making does not match the timing of when you configured the bucket for CORS, and may have been cached before your bucket's CORS settings were in the correct state, or before they matched those you've posted in the question.

If an `Origin:` header was present on that request, as the browser shows that it was, then S3 should have added the CORS response headers, whether or not the request was actually a cross-origin request.

Your next steps would be to try this with a new object at a new path that there is no possibility of being cached, or try the common browser cache-busting tactic of adding `?some-random=thing-here` to the object's URL when making the request.  Failing that, you should consider proving or disproving correct behavior by your bucket using a tool like `curl` that shows exactly what's happening in the request/response.

Comment: I did some more testing with some new images to ensure that there was no possibility of prior caching. What I found was that (at least in Safari), the Network tab was telling me that the second request was being served from the cache. So even though it had the proper header, somehow, the browser was serving the cached version that didn't have the `Origin` header. I decided to try your approach of adding a random query parameter to the url and it seems to be holding up so far.

Comment: Okay, here's a suggestion.  Change your bucket CORS config to `<AllowedOrigin>http://example.com</AllowedOrigin>` (using your actual domain).  If you have more than one (https of the same host would be a different origin than http) then create an identical `<CORSRule>...</CORSRule>` block for each origin.  Safari might be calling BS on the wildcard without actually telling you so.

Comment: No dice. I tried that approach. I created a policy with specific origins and a wildcard origin and it failed. Also tried with only specific origins (no wildcard rule) and it still failed. I'm pretty certain it's a caching issue at this point. That cache busting trick you suggested is the only thing that seems to work for me.

Comment: @ACIDSTEALTH I believe you were correct all along... your issue may indeed be caching issue, a case of problematic behavior on the part of S3.  It should be returning `Vary: Origin` in non-CORS responses, but it does not. See https://serverfault.com/a/856948/153161 for analysis of the issue and a workaround using Lambda@Edge.

Comment: Interesting find there! If I recall correctly I ended up just appending a query string to the end of each file name (e.g. utm=1234556789) with a unix timestamp to force the browser to request the file again.